# text message notification interrupting voice calls samsung galaxy s2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, notifications

Does anyone know how to turn off the notification for text messages that breaks into voice calls on my Sprint Samsung Galaxy s2 (SPH-D710)?

Comment: Do you want to turn them off permanently, or just during calls?

Answer (score 2):

On my S2 (SGH-S959G) the setting is in `Settings App > Call > Call Alert > Uncheck Alerts on Call`.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Galaxy S3 has a setting within the Phone Dialer "Call Settings\Call Alert\Alerts on call". Unchecking this will prevent alerts from interfereing a phone call. This is probably similar on your Galaxy S2.